# Must I delete my SQL class or improve it? C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, class

I have a class that stores the code snippet that I usually use for SQL queries.

Example, I use this method to fill `datagridviews.Datasource` with things like products, providers, clients, and any data that I need in a table:

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(string query)
{
    using (SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        _connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, _connection))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

I have similar things for commands and readers. The only problem was that with readers I was populating a `list<string>` with the first record in a `SqlDataReader`, so I had to run readers outside of class to deal with things like combo boxes. Trying to fix this problem, I started to think that it might be better to just put the code for the queries where I need it and not create a new `ExecuteReader` method to run the `Data.SqlClient` `ExecuteReader` method.

I don't know if this class is a good idea or if I am wasting time trying to improve it and there are different and better ways to deal with this kind of thing. What do you think about?

Comment: Rather than `DataTable`s I would suggest reading up on Dapper.

Comment: @mjwills Yesterday I didn't know that Dapper existed, I think I will try to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a method that returns a typed list with data from the database, you can do this:

```
public List<T> GetList<T>(string query, Func<SqlDataReader, T> func)
{
    var list = new List<T>();

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        using (var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var item = func(reader);
                list.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

That is, set the method for creating and filling in the object as a lambda function.
Use it like this:

```
var departments = GetList<Department>(
    "select Id, Name from Department",
    reader => new Department(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1)) // using constructor
);

var orders = GetList<Order>(
    "select Id, Price, Date from Order",
    reader => new Order // using properties
    {
        Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
        Price = reader.GetDecimal(1),
        Date = reader.GetDateTime(2)
    }
);
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

I too have done similar in my apps to have a centralized place to send my queries, get error trapping in case of failure and return a datatable.  I have since changed to querying strongly-typed result sets, but the premise is the same.

To expand on what you have, you may want to wrap it up one more by allowing for a full SQLCommand to be passed in which may be parameterized.  You do not want to just concatenate a string together with...

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "select .. from .. where x = " + SomeVariableFromUncontrolledSource;
```

You would be asking for SQL Injection.

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(string query)
{
   var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand( query );
   return GetDataTable( sqlcmd );
}

public DataTable GetDataTable(SqlCommand sqlcmd)
{
   using (SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
   {
      _connection.Open();
      using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd, _connection))
      {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         adapter.Fill(dt);
         return dt;
      }
   }
}
```

Again, you probably want to wrap try/catch such a bad sql connection, bad query command, bad parameters provided, bad read back, etc...  But the benefit DOES exist for it to be centralized and not duplicating the open, close connection, try / trap errors too.  And by Overloading the function to allow a simple string, OR a fully prepared SqlCommand, you have both going to same central place.